# facebook asynchronous validation doesn't show errors

Tags: xfbml, facebook-javascript-sdk

The javascript console keeps showing "Not a custom field name: username" when its supposed to show an error for the username field. There clearly is a field named "username". I tried changing it to some other name everywhere, but it still didn't work. 
Any idea what is going on?

```
<fb:registration redirect-uri="<?=$pageurl?>" 
  fields="[{'name':'name'},{'name':'email'},{'name':'location'},{'name':'username','description':'Username','type':'text'},{'name':'password','view':'not_prefilled'},{'name':'captcha','view':'not_prefilled'}]"
  onvalidate="validate" width="400"></fb:registration>
```

and my validate function...

```
function validate(form,cb)
{
    console.dir(form);  
    $.get('/api/?f=user_email_present&username='+form.username+"&email="+form.email,function(data){
        console.log(data);
        if(data.username==false)
        {
            cb();
        }
        else 
        {
            if(data.username=='username')
                cb({username: 'That username is already taken. Please try another username.'});
            else if(data.username=='usernamelength')
                cb({username: 'The username cannot exceed 20 characters in length.'});

        }
    });
}
```

I can't be too sure, but I think I remember all this working a while back. Took me by complete shock when we are 2 days from launch.

Update: I scrapped out asynchronous validation and used the other validation. It still throws the same error!

Comment: What exactly do you want to do here? I may be wrong, but most of the xfbml methods through facebook are deprecated (or in the process of becoming so). This would cause you errors (and may be the case if the method was working and is not now)

Comment: facebook has deprecated fbml, not xfbml tags. Infact, you can't use server side asynchronous validation with the iframe version of the registration plugin. Only the xfbml version allows that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending the better part of two days, I managed to figure out what is going on. It is a silly but potent bug on facebook's end. If the width of the widget is too less, it gives this error. Increasing the width to 800px fixed it promptly. Probably they don't render the proper error fields when the width is too small.
I have filed a bug report: https://github.com/facebook/connect-js/issues/275
If you guys can give it a shot and comment on my bug report so that they can take action immediately, it would be awesome.

Comment: It looks like you hit "Comment & Close" instead of "Comment" on GitHub. (I do that a lot.) You'll need to open a new Issue if you want the Facebook team to see it. If you repost, I'll gladly comment. :)

Comment: hey.. thanks for pointing it out. New issue: https://github.com/facebook/connect-js/issues/278